# Show new field from count result in other table

Tags: sql

i have the problem in query. i want to show one field that contain result from count on other table. hard to explain but i hope you can help me.
so the result that i want like :

```
select id, name, car from tbl_people,tbl_vehicle
```

the 'car' field is the result from count(vehicle) in vehicle table, which the fields in that table are id, and vehicle. the vehicle field contains (ex) car, bicycle, motorcycle, (any other vehicle)
the result that i want is like :

```
id | name  |  car  
-----------------
01 | john  |  3 (example)
```

thank you for your attention

Comment: Please show sample data that for your desired results.

Comment: i have, just say, two table, person and vehicle. in person the field like id, and name. and in vehicle like id, vehicle_name. vehicle_name containing ex : car, bicycle, (other vehicle). i want the result like table that i draw on my question. could you help me?

Comment: You con't have any connection between the two tables, so it is a bit difficult to understand what you want for the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you end up with a sub query.  Not sure about your IDs, but something like:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.cnt 
from tbl_people p
inner join
   (select personid, count(1) as Cnt
   from tbl_vehicle
   where vehicle_name = 'Car'
   group by personid) v
on v.personid = p.id
order by p.name
```

Comment: is that will count other vehicle too? i just need one specific field counted. how if i add where vehicle_name='car'? and where can i place it?

Comment: @RezaKahfi see edit, I added: where vehicle_name = 'Car'

Answer (score 0):

you could try this too:

```
select t1.id, t1.DeptID, count(t2.DeptId) as count 
from t1 join t2 on t1.DeptID=t2.DeptId group by t2.DeptId;
```

replace t1 and t2 with the respective table names and the columns with the appropriate column names. If you want a where clause you could add it before the group by clause like:

```
select t1.id, t1.DeptID, count(t2.DeptId) as count 
from t1 join t2 on t1.DeptID=t2.DeptId and t2.Name like '%a%'
group by t2.DeptId;
```

Working fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f563/2)

Hint:  Let t1 be the tbl_people and t2 be the tbl_vehicle. The join would be on the ids, and the count(t2.DeptId) can be replaced with tbl_vehicle.ID (if that is repeating or tbl_vehicle.pId) and t2.Name can be replaced with tbl_vehicle.Name